# mysql join query double

Tags: mysql, join, double

tables are here :

[image]

**i want to write ;**

*match 1: jonathan vs jenny ,*

*match 2: sam vs ruby,*

*match 3: arif vs pamee*

---

I tried lots of queries but failed to accomplish it.

```
SELECT table1.boy_id, table1.girl_id, table1.ID, table2.id, table2.name, table2.score
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        b.name BoyName,
        c.name GirlName
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            On a.boy_id = b.id
        INNER JOIN table2 c
            ON a.girl_id = c.id
```

You need to join `table2` twice on `table1` since there are two columns from `table1` that references to `table2`.